# Texture Stretching at Gluteal Cleft on Character Model in Blender 4.1

Tags: mesh, texturing, uv

I've encountered an issue with my character model in Blender 4.1, where the texture appears to be stretching improperly around the gluteal cleft area. Despite having checked the UV map for overlaps and ensuring it's laid out correctly, the problem persists. I have also verified that the texture resolution is sufficient and the UVs are properly unwrapped. The issue is not with the image's resolution, as it appears to be adequate for other parts of the model.

I'm considering utilizing shaders to correct or mitigate the stretching appearance. Could anyone suggest shader adjustments or techniques in Blender that might help refine the texture appearance specifically in this challenging area? Any advice on how to employ bump or normal mapping effectively to address this issue would be highly appreciated. Here's a visual reference to the problem area[image]

Comment: It is unclear to me what the problem is. Where is the texture stretched? What does the UV map look like? Why do you want to use a bump or a normal map? I can see that the mesh is way more dense at the back/waist area than at the butt area. However, this should not necessarily be a problem for texturing. You still can remove a few edge loops at the back or add more edge loops at the butt to obtain a more uniform density. Or just adjust the UV map to lower the stretching.

Comment: The mesh topology is not ideal in the selected area. There are several 6-star and 7-star-poles and unnecessary triangulated faces (tris). The poles can cause bad deformations and the tris makes it harder to work with the model in Blender because you cannot select edge loops properly. It also can result in shading issues. I think that is what you mean by "texture stretching", the bright triangles, right? I would add 3 more horizontal edge loops to smooth it. But fix the topology first.